# Travis CI build fails on react-native android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, npm, travis-ci

I am trying to build my react-native project with travis ci using this command:

```
script: 
    - npm install -g npx && cd android && sudo chmod +x gradlew && sudo ./gradlew assembleRelease#3
```

However, my build fails with the following error:
     Cannot run program "npx": error=2, No such file or directory

My full config if as follows:

```
language: android
before_install: #1.1
- nvm install 10
- node --version
install: #1.2
- npm install
android: #1.3
  components:
  - build-tools-23.0.1
  - android-23
  - extra-android-m2repository
  - extra-google-google_play_services
  - extra-google-m2repository
  - addon-google_apis-google-16
script: 
    - npm install -g npx && cd android && sudo chmod +x gradlew && sudo ./gradlew assembleRelease#3
deploy: # mostly generated by `> travis deploy releases`
  skip_cleanup: true
```

It seems as though the build file is unable to find npx even though I have installed globally with npm. In the native_modules.gradle files where the errors, the error line is as follows:

```
def npx = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) ? "npx.cmd" : "npx"
```

Here is a call stack where the error occurs:

```
Welcome to Gradle 5.5!
1776
1777
Here are the highlights of this release:
1778
 - Kickstart Gradle plugin development with gradle init
1779
 - Distribute organization-wide Gradle properties in custom Gradle distributions
1780
 - Transform dependency artifacts on resolution
1781
1782
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/release-notes.html
1783
1784
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
1785
1786
1787
> Starting Daemon<-------------> 0% INITIALIZING [21ms]<-------------> 0% INITIALIZING [121ms]> Evaluating settings<-------------> 0% INITIALIZING [221ms]<-------------> 0% INITIALIZING [321ms]<-------------> 0% INITIALIZING [421ms]<-------------> 0% INITIALIZING [521ms]<-------------> 0% INITIALIZING [621ms]<-------------> 0% INITIALIZING [721ms]<-------------> 0% INITIALIZING [822ms]> Evaluating settings > Compiling /home/travis/build/daniel-sudz/bbox-mobile/an<-------------> 0% INITIALIZING [921ms]<-------------> 0% INITIALIZING [1s]> Evaluating settings> Evaluating settings > Compiling /home/travis/build/daniel-sudz/bbox-mobile/no> Evaluating settingsmand from 'null' directory failed.
1788
1789
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
1790
1791
* Where:
1792
Script '/home/travis/build/daniel-sudz/bbox-mobile/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle' line: 154
1793
1794
* What went wrong:
1795
A problem occurred evaluating script.
1796
> Cannot run program "npx": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Note: the build occurs on ubuntu

Any ideas on what the solution may be?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my issue by adding openjdk8 and setting my android sdk path. Full working config for me:

```
os:
- linux
before_install:
- curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
- sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
- npm --version
- node --version
- npx --version
- export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk
- export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
- export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
- export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
- export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
- git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git -b v4.9.0 --depth 1
- cd watchman
- "./autogen.sh"
- "./configure"
- make
- sudo make install
- cd ..
install:
- npm install
language: android
jdk:
- oraclejdk8
dist: trusty
android:
  components:
  - tools
  - platform-tools
  - build-tools-28.0.3
  - android-28
  - extra-google-google_play_services
  - extra-google-m2repository
  - extra-android-m2repository
script:
- cd android && sudo chmod +x gradlew && sudo ./gradlew clean && sudo ./gradlew assembleRelease
- cd ..
```